# Require_once config.php not working with function php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with my code, hope everyone can help me.

This is my config.php

```
$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "vertrigo";
$db_name = "DBname";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $db_user , $db_pass, $db_name);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'UTF8');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "<br />";
  echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
  exit;
}
```

I require it into index.php with function lib like

```
require_once("config.php");
require("lib/select.php");
```

This is my select lib

```
function SelectAdmin()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * from admin order by id ASC";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    return $result; 
}
```

Then, i'm call it in index.php

```
while ($rows = SelectAdmin()->fetch_assoc()) 
{ 
    echo $rows['Fullname'];
}
```

But it show error

> Undefined variable: mysqli in .... \lib\select.php on line 8

Please help me. Thank you !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function SelectAdmin() {
    global $mysqli;//You need this !
    $sql = "SELECT * from admin order by id ASC";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: If this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).

Comment: you should not use global instead pass the $mysqli variable to the function

Comment: @ArunKumaresh Why ? elaborate !!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why

Comment: @ArunKumaresh Okay, please help me to spot "DO NOT USE" ? Because there is NONE !

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic scope problem.

You declared `$mysqli` in the "main" scope, let's call it "level 0", and now you want to access it in `SelectAdmin()`. But there is no `$mysqli` variable defined in that method, because within that method your are at "level 1".

You can tell `SelectAdmin()` to use the variable at level 0 by marking that variable as global: `global $mysqli`.

Or even better, you can define a `Connect()` method that makes the connection every time you need it.

So in `SelectAdmin()` you will have to call `$mysqli = Connect()` and that should work in every method where you need a connection.

Answer (score 0):

pass the $mysqli to the function so that it can get access to the $mysqli varible

```
function SelectAdmin($mysqli) {
    $sql = "SELECT * from admin order by id ASC";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    return $result; 
}
```